# What causes urn:acme:error:unauthorized 403 error in golang's acme/autocert?

Tags: go, https, dns, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

The full error message is:

> 403 urn:acme:error:unauthorized: Account creation on ACMEv1 is
> disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports
> ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See
> https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430
> for details

And I've googled this and reviewed that link, but I'm just using:

`golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert`

package in a very normal way:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert"
)

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    hosts := []string{"yourdomain.com"}
    certManager := autocert.Manager{
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(hosts...),
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("/certs"),
    }

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":https",
        Handler: router,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate,
        },
    }

    server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
}
```

In fact this code has been running and working fine for the last 6 months. But just today I switched the server it was on and now get the above message.

I tried getting the very latest version of golang, but still same problem.

I changed my DNS for my hosts to this new server's ip and the hostname of the server is correct.

Far as I can tell, it's 100% identical to the previous working server but with a new IP.

Is golang's acme/autocert really this out of date and not using ACMEv2?

Comment: You need to update your certbot software/library, it is too old.   Like the error message says, the API has changed on Let's Encrypt some time ago hence the clients need to be updated.

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme seems to provide ACMEv2

Comment: @Patrick there is no certbot software! This is using golang's library directly.

Comment: Yes... which is why I said "certbot software/library". Note the "library".

Comment: and yet, everything I can find says the golang library is ACMEv2.

Comment: And yet, the error message your quote clearly says the software is not using ACMEv2. Look if there is maybe some settings forcing ACMEv1 that should be removed. Obviously, also try from another computer and/or another version of the library.

Comment: found this line https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/blob/065cfd502fe52fad16b128094c59daf6e8e0b885/wfe/wfe.go#L651 must be hitting here from https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/6ca56c2f2e2b26dc733347707d0e75d8eb050ee1/acme/acme.go#L375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

> In fact this code has been running and working fine for the last 6 months. But just today I switched the server it was on and now get the above message.

Might indicate that you're building against an older version of `golang.org/x/crypto` - check your `go.mod` file and ensure you're using a fairly recent version.  I completed a project recently that uses almost identical code.  The `require` in my `go.mod` looks like this:

```
golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20200602180216-279210d13fed
```

Comment: look at that, my go.mod had golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2 changing to the 2020 version fixed it! Thank u!!